# ASP.net 1.1 Maintain Value on PostBack when Modified in

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, viewstate, asp.net-1.1

I have to support and develop a few features for an old Asp.net 1.1 website. Unfortunately, it was written more like a classic ASP site than ASP.net. They used include files with scriptlets for core logic. This means all the core logic runs on Render instead of PageLoad.

One of the problems with this seems to be that when I modify values for asp.net controls, the values do not get persisted across postbacks.

I'm assuming this happens because ViewState has already been finalized at this point. Is there anyway to refresh ViewState later in the pipeline? Or am I going to have to reload all my values on every postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reloading the values is what a classic ASP site would do. The developers no doubt assumed that.

I recommend you don't violate their assumptions.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing :(